# Conditional logic based on two datasets in SQL/Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression

So I have two datasets in a database

**DF1**

```
ID value
001    A
002    A
003    B
004    C
```

And I have this other data set as follows

```
ID     content
002    walter
003    hank
```

So all I want to do is make a Common Table Expression(CTE) in Snowflake where if an ID in DF1 appears in DF2, then a new variable indicates this (1 or 0)

Final result

```
ID value  id_exist
001    A         0
002    A         1
003    B         1
004    C         0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with DF1 as
(
    select * from (values (1, 'A'), (2, 'A'), (3, 'B'), (4, 'C')) as X(ID, VALUE)
),
DF2 as
(
    select ID, CONTENT from (values (2, 'Walter'), (3, 'Hank')) as X(ID, CONTENT)
)
select DF1.ID, DF1.VALUE, iff(DF2.ID is not null, 1, 0) as ID_EXISTS  from DF1 left join DF2 on DF1.ID = DF2.ID
;
```

Answer (score 2):

If wanting to use a CTE, you could do this:

```
    with cte1 as
    (select 1 as vcount, id
     from df2
    )
    select a.id, a.value, coalesce(b.vcount, 0) as id_exist
    from df1 a
    left join cte1 b
      on b.id = a.id
```